# Topology: Is there a name for spaces that are not even $T_0$?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

Is there a name for topological spaces that fail to be $T_0$?

Thanks!

Comment: I originally said "pathological" kind of as a joke, but I took it down because I didn't want to be misleading. I don't know of any particular name for such spaces and I don't think there is one.

Comment: non-T$_0$ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Haha funny guy

Comment: You could say “non-Kolmogorov space.”

Comment: We have a name for spaces that ARE $T_0$, why would we need a special, different name for the ones that aren't ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not heard of one, and I would suspect not since such spaces simply aren't mathematically interesting save for the occasional desired counterexample.  If a space isn't even $T_0$, then you can find points $x$ and $y$ such that $x$ and $y$ have the exact same neighborhoods.  In this sense, there's no reason to even *talk* about $x$ and $y$ individually; it is more natural / more efficient to talk about the *set of points* that are topologically indistinguishable from $x.$

This line of reasoning leads us to the idea behind the [Kolmogorov quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_space#The_Kolmogorov_quotient).  Notice that topological indistinguishability is an equivalence relation, so we can take a given non-$T_0$ space $X$ and construct the quotient space $X/ \! \sim$.  By collapsing topologically indistinguishable points down to single equivalence classes in the quotient space, we've constructed a space that is now $T_0$, and we've lost no essential information doing so.

Comment: We have lost the set of cardinalities of the sets of "touching" points. This is essential information.